# Partial document update in solr

Tags: apache, solr

I m using apache solr , I want to do partial update of document in solr

I am new to Apachesolr and i m using windows operating system please help me and give suitable example for this

we need to update a single field in the index and we don’t want to send the whole document. Lets say, that we need to update product price, which is updated a few times a day. We don’t want to index the whole document again and again,

Comment: What version of solr are you using? As of 4.0 you can achieve this using atomic updates. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates

Answer (score 2):

Also:

Look at http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/

Interestingly the site above uses the same product price example that you are trying to solve.

Note that your entire document(all fields) needs to be stored for this to happen.